# How to deal with my login_required url?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have:

Linker urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$',
        include('distributors.urls', namespace='distributors')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

App urls:

```
url(r'^$', views.Index.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^links/$', login_required(views.LinkListView.as_view(), name='links'),
```

in my html i have `href="{% url 'distributors:index' %}"` and `href="{% url 'distributors:links' %}"`

Views:

```
class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "distributors/index.html"


class LinkListView(ListView):
    model = Link
    template_name = "distributors/links.html"
    context_object_name = 'links'
```

When I try to enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I see `The included urlconf 'linker.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: share your linker.urls contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly remove the dollar sign when including other url patterns.

```
url(r'^',
    include('distributors.urls', namespace='distributors')),
```

Secondly, you are missing a closing bracket where you are using `login_required`.

```
url(r'^links/$', login_required(views.LinkListView.as_view()), name='links'),
```

Comment: still same error. I have found that there are some problems with using login_required ulrs and reversing them, but i still cannot handle it.

Comment: You are using `login_required` incorrectly - I've updated my answer.